# Microsoft Azure - Cannot access MySQL Instance running on Docker from outside the VM

Tags: mysql, azure, docker, ip, virtual-machine

I created a VM (Ubuntu Server 18.04) on Microsoft Azure Cloud on which I installed Docker and I'm running a MySQL 5.7 container.

The problem is when I try to connect to MySQL instance from outside the VM (MySQL Workbench for example which is installed directly on my computer) I receive an error like:

```
Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at my_ip_address:3306: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my_ip_address' (60)
```

I am suspecting that my VM doesn't allow external IP access but I couldn't figure out how to allow some IPs using Azure

Comment: Are you able to connect from the Ubuntu server using mysql client? If not, how are you running the docker instance?

Comment: Get your connection working from the server, and then focus on how to achieve a remote connection.

Comment: @danblack you mean I check MySQL connection between **VM <-> Docker** before **My computre <-> VM <-> Docker** ?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT as far as now it's good but I'm can't configure mysql server config file as said here [https://serverfault.com/questions/928432/cant-connect-to-workbench-on-newly-installed-linux-and-mysql-on-azure/928466#928466] because I can't find the file **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf**

Comment: @ghassen The solution I provide in the case is the MySQL installed in the Azure Ubuntu VM, not the container. There is something difference between them. You just need to create the user for MySQL without configuring the mysqld.cnf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a container with running MySQL in it on Azure VM of Ubuntu 18.04. You can follow the steps below. And finally, you will connect to it.

**First.**

Create the container with running MySQL in it and the command here:

```
docker run --name=mysql -d -p 3306:3306 mysql/mysql-server:latest
```

When finish it, you can use the command to see the password of the root user:

```
docker logs mysql
```

The result will like this:
[image]

Then use the command to connect mysql:

```
docker exec -it mysql mysql -uroot -p
```

And change the password:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
```

Now you can exit and use the root user with your new password to connect mysql.

**Second.**

Create a user to remote connects MySQL, you can follow another [case](https://serverfault.com/questions/928432/cant-connect-to-workbench-on-newly-installed-linux-and-mysql-on-azure/928466#928466) which I answered.

**Third.**

Create the rule to allow the traffic of port 3306 on the Azure portal.

[image]

It works on my site and hopes this will help you.

**Update**

You can add the Network Security Group rules here like the screenshot shows:

[image]

Comment: thank you for you message .. but I can't find how to open the port on Azure Portal .. Can you explain more please ?

Comment: On my screen I don't have **Networking** under **Settings**, I have just Network Security Group ! For information I am on a trial subscription .. might be this the cause ?

Comment: @ghassen You just need add rules to the Network Security Group which associated to your VM network interface and the subnet in Vnet.

Comment: I don't have access to portal. I have access to Azure VM. So, I wanted to check If any particular inbound port is open or not. so, I ma running

Comment: @PSatishPatro If you can run CLI command to access the NSG, use the command [`az network nsg rule list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nsg/rule?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-nsg-rule-list) to get the rules.

Comment: @CharlesXu, that should run in azure-cli? Is login not required?

Comment: @PSatishPatro No, it's Azure CLI. You can run in Linux or windows.

Comment: @CharlesXu For now what I am doing running ES in different port and checking in browser. Is there any better way or that is what i can do?

Comment: @CharlesXu, but I don't have azure credentials to do "az login"

Comment: @PSatishPatro That's a shame. Run Azure command is a simple way. The NSG is the Azure resource. So there is no other simple way as I know if you do not have the Azure account.

Comment: @CharlesXu  got it

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using the [SSH tunnel feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-methods-ssh.html) of Workbench then you don't need to make you're database accessible remotely.

Comment: That's what I did exactly but it doesn't work .. I was following this [tuto] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal) to open 3306 but at final step I can't find the screen of **Subnet Assoication** like mentionned

Comment: 'doesn't work' doesn't provide any information that would be required to move you past whatever obstacle you hit.

Comment: This is the error that I hit : 
13.69.122.96:3306:
  Can't connect to MySQL server on '13.69.122.96' (60)
Please:
1 Check that mysql is running on server 13.69.122.96
2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the root has rights to connect to 13.69.122.96 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 13.69.122.96 connecting from the host address you're connecting from

Answer (score 0):

If you created the VM with the default values. You can check the firewall rules on the Networking section. There you should see the allowed traffic for inbound and outbound. By default VMs on azure have a NSG (Network Security Group) associated unless you change that property on creation or edit it after creation.

Once you checked that NSG has the right settings. I guess the default port for MySQL is TCP 3306. If the rule is not present add it.

After that, you should check Ubuntu firewall. I think by default is up.

Try this:

```
sudo ufw status
```

and then this:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

It will disable Firewall, check if you can connect to the MySQL instance. If you successfully connect to it, then enable Ubuntu Firewall with:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

And add a Firewall Rule to allow incoming traffic to TCP Port 3306 on the OS:

```
sudo ufw allow from any to any port 3306 proto tcp
```

Restart firewall and check if the new rule is active with:

```
sudo ufw status
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Comment: Advising people to drop all network security on public VMs is just asking for those to be turned into botnets/spambots when they do get compromised. There are mechanisms that facilitate secure access, so help the SO users get their desired outcome without compromising their security.

Comment: Hi @danblack I agree with you completely. But I didn't suggest to leave the firewall down. For testing purposes, this is part of the troubleshooting. Also take into consideration that the VM has a firewall in front of it (NSG) besides the OS firewall. Even if you disable OS firewall you are protected by the VM NSG. But, I will add a clarification on my post.